# Regex / javax.validation help -- verifying non-whitespace present -- Java

Tags: java, regex, validation

I'm trying to validate some fields before persisting them to the database.  In particular, I need to know that a String contains a non-whitespace character.

I'm using the `javax.validation.constraints.Pattern` annotation, as follows:

```
@Pattern(regexp = "[^\\s]")
private String field;
```

This seems to throw the ConstraintViolation on every String.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\S` (or its equivalent `[^\s]`) should work according to the docs. Do you think it's putting an automatic `"^" + expr + "$"`? According to the docs it shouldn't, but maybe try `.*\S.*`

(from my comment -- thought this answer was a total shot in the dark; got lucky. Those docs could use some revising...)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `"[\\s]+"`. The `+` ensures one or more of this character class occurs.

---

Edit: If I re-read the question, I wonder if you enter Strings like "A dog runs" and it breaks because there are non-whitespace characters, but there are also whitespace characters. Try this:

```
((\\s+)?([^\\s]))+
```

---

Last thing: Not sure why you have a `private void field` -- was that supposed to be a `String`?

Comment: Seems plausible, but no, that doesn't change anything.

Comment: `\S` (or its equivalent `[^\s]`) should work according to the docs. Do you think it's putting an automatic `"^" + expr + "$"`? According to the docs it shouldn't, but maybe try `.*\S.*`

Comment: @Ian - That's it.  Post as an answer, and I'll upvote and accept.